# Boost Unit Test timing mechanism

Tags: c++, performance, unit-testing, boost

Is there some built-in mechanism in the Boost Unit Test framework to check for timing issues. For example to:

- Report timing of every test
- Check for tests exceeding a given time limit
- Any thing time related you know of

I've tried to use the command line parameter such as --report_level or --log_level, but it didn't report anything related to timing.

Thanks

Comment: For the second bullet point, your individual unit tests should be doing that themselves.  Create a base time, do your operation, and calculate how long it took from the base time.  Then assert that it's less than X.  This documents clearly that the unit must finish its operation in that time.

Comment: Do you think this check could be done in the destructor of a fixture to minimize the code duplication?

Answer (score 1):

1. Report timing of every test:
   For Boost.Test to report timings, you need to specify "--report_level=detailed --log_level=all". The test timings will be lost in the output but will look like :

> Leaving test case "my_test_1"; testing time: 220mks
>   Leaving test case"my_test_2"; testing time: 219mks
>   ...

2. Check for tests exceeding a given time limit :
   I have never tested it, but boost test framework offers a [decorator timeout](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/testing_tools/timeout.html)

Comment: '--log_level=test_suite' seems already enough.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can specify timeout for the test case
2. Boost.Test report time for each test unit in detailed report mode
3. I am looking to implement much more advanced tools for timing tests soon(ish)

Comment: How do you specify timeout for the test case? On the command line?

Comment: @GennadiyRozental: any progress on (3)?